# How do I redirect users from the server IP to the URL with path?

Tags: 8, redirection

I'm working on a Drupal site. Everything works when I access the site using its IP address. My supervisor made an Nginx redirection on another server to the site's IP. Now the site should be accessible from http://example.com/services/drupal, but it isn't.

I have tried modifying the settings.php file with the following lines.

```
$base_url = 'example.com/services/drupal';
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = [
    '^example.com$',
    '^example\.com\/services\/drupal$',
    '^example\.com\/services\/drupal',
];
$base_path = 'services/drupal';
```

How could I get my site to work correctly on http://example.com/services/drupal?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The `$settings['trusted_host_patterns']` array is only for the domain, not for domain and path. That doesn't explain why the site isn't accessible from http://example.com/services/drupal, though.

Comment: Does the IP points to example.com or to a different domain name?

Comment: Thanks for a welcome! IP does not point to any domain name.

Comment: The question speaks of IP, but the code sets the base URL to example.com/services/drupal, which I take it means example.com is a domain name associated to that IP that works when used in a browser. (_Everything works if in the browser I use the IP address to connect to the site. My supervisor made an Nginx redirection on another server to the site's IP._) Also, what's that Nginix redirection?

Comment: A domain name doesn't work, if it's not associated to an IP. That's true for any domain name, including stackexchange.com or drupal.org.